# Dynamic creation of subdomains

Tags: yii, wildcard-subdomain

I'm creating a website using MVC framework (Yii) and I need to dynamically create subdomains, i.e. *http://company.website.com*

So, in order to achieve this I've added a DNS wildcard (*.website.com). Now the problem is that my application controllers are all the same for www.website.com and for company.website.com. For example, I have a `User` controller with `Register` action (`user/register`). Now if I go to **www.website.com/user/register** I can register, but I can do *exactly* the same if I go to **company.website.com/user/register**. And this behaviour is the same for all my controllers.

I realize everything is working correctly, but how do I separate controllers for www.website.com and for compnay.website.com? I don't want users to access register/login/other controllers and actions from the subdomian url.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could include hostname into your routing rules array. For example, you could create rules

```
array(
    'http://www.website.com/user/register' => 'user/register',
    'http://<company:\w+>.website.com/user/register' => 'other/route',
)
```

and check for `company` parameter in your `other/route` action. Please note that `http://` is required for those rules to work. See [CUrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CUrlManager) documentation for more details.

P.S. If controllers for `http://www.website.com` and `http://company.website.com/user/register` are completely different it could be better to set up two applications for those sites.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a pretty old thread, but it doesn't wanna work for me. Do I have to change settings on my `vhosts` file or the `hosts` file on windows (Apache)?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, the 'company' component of the URL is a variable company name. I'll continue my answer under that assumption.

Another option would be to create a company module (I'll call it 'Companies' for now), and use the CUrlManager rules to route to that controller. E.g.

```
array(
    'http://<company:\w+>.website.com/user/register' => '/companies/user/register',
    'http://<company:\w+>.website.com/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>' => '/companies/<_c>/<_a>' // more generic option
),
```

The 'company' string will be passed to the application as $_GET['company'] and you can use this parameter in your CompaniesModule.php file to load some company specific data.

Please note that without some other rule to handle www.website.com requests (as per Grey Teardrop's answer) you will get errors on requests to that subdomain.