# Dynamic Subdomain Using Url Rewriting in yii

Tags: .htaccess, yii, url-rewriting, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I want to create ***dynamic sub domain*** .I want to do with help of ***yii framework***.
By giving url will generate virtual sub domain.

I have below url.

```
http://www.xyz.com/dq/logic/pd[controller]/dispall [method]/web [parameter 1]/web-designer [parameter 2]
```

From this url to I want to convert below url

```
http://web[ parameter 1].xyz.com/dq/logic/pd[method]/dispall[method]/web-designer [parameter 2].
```

Any one can help me about this ?

Comment: How are these subdomains getting created in `VirtualHost`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic creation of subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390533/dynamic-creation-of-subdomains)

Comment: I checked both of the answers these are not working for me and mine question is quite different from them.